# Converging sequence of functions; real functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, cauchy-sequences, sequence-of-function

I am stuck on this exercise. We are studying the boundary value problem
\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases} 
 u(x) - u''(x) = f(x),&x \in (0,1) \\
 u(0) = u(1) = 0 \\ 
 \end{cases}
 \label{prob}
\end{equation}

which has the solution (in compact form) 
\begin{equation}
 u(x) = \int_{0}^{1}G(x,y)(f(y) - u(y))dy
 \label{sol}
\end{equation}
Where $G(x,y)$ is the Greens functions for this specific boundary value problem. We later define $\mathcal{H}$ as the mapping from $C([0,1])$ to $C_{0}([0,1])$ by
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{H}(v)(x) = \int_{0}^{1}G(x,y)(f(y) - v(y))dy
\end{equation} 
and the sequence of solutions $\{u_n\}_{n = 0}^{\infty}$ by

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u_0(x) = 0\\
u_{n+1}(x) = \mathcal{H}(u_n)(x),&n\geq 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

From a previous exercise I have already shown that $$
 ||\mathcal{H}(v)-\mathcal{H}(u)||_{\infty} \leq  \frac{1}{8}||u - v||_{\infty}
$$

I wish to show that $$u(x) = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} u_n$$ exists and that $u(x)$ solves the problem.

Can I somehow use this result to show that the sequence converges and thus showing that the boundary value problem has a unique solution, or do I have to delve into the world of Cauchy analysis?

Comment: Unless I've missed something obvious, you haven't said what it is you're meant to be showing?

Comment: @RhysSteele you are absolutely right, I have edited the post now.

Answer (score 1):

To see that $u_n$ converges in $C([0,1])$, it suffices to check that it is a Cauchy sequence for the $\infty$-norm since $C([0,1])$ is complete for that norm. For this, the thing you showed in the previous exercise is enough. Indeed, that inequality implies that
\begin{align}
\|u_{n+1} - u_n\| = \|\mathcal{H}(u_n) - \mathcal{H}(u_{n-1})\| \leq 8^{-1} \|u_n - u_{n-1}\| \leq \dots \leq 8^{-(n-1)} \|u_2 - u_1\|
\end{align}
and as a result that for $m > n$
\begin{align}
\|u_m - u_n\| \leq \sum_{j = n}^{m-1} \|u_{j+1} - u_j\| \leq \|u_2 - u_1\| \sum_{j = n}^\infty 8^{-(j-1)} \to 0 
\end{align}
as $n \to \infty$ so that $u_n$ is a Cauchy sequence as desired. Hence there exists $u \in C_0([0,1])$ such that $\|u_n - u\| \to 0$.

Now we know that
$$u_{n+1} = \int_0^1 G(\cdot,y) (f(y) - u_n(y)) dy$$
and so by sending $n \to \infty$ we get that
$$u = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 G(\cdot, y)(f(y)-u_n(y))dy = \int_0^1 G(\cdot,y)(f(y)-u(y))dy$$
where we can pass the limit through the integral since convergence for the $\infty$-norm is uniform convergence. This is exactly that $u$ solves the integral form of ODE we started with, as desired.